# Estimating extra maintenance cost when using GSI in a DynamoDB table

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Users table in DynamoDB that has a unique hash key `username`. I want, however, to be able to find a specific user in the most efficient way possible by providing either just the username, or just the email (the email is also unique). I can make the email a global secondary index, but I have a trouble estimating the additional cost of this approach. Will using the index to retrieve a user result in two read operations? Or how many operations exactly?

Also, I want read and write throughput of the index to equal those of the table (and ideally, scale automatically), can I do that by not providing specific throughput values when I create the index with API, or do I have to provide them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The number of read operations you will need to retrieve values from the index will depend on what values you want to read (all of them vs just a subset) and what the projection type for the index is. If the projection is ALL then it only takes 1 read, but it may cost more. If the projection is KEYS_ONLY you will only get back the table's primary key, then you would have to query the table again by that. That takes more than 1 read, but may be cheaper. It will all depend on your use cases and usage patterns.

See "Attribute Projections" at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html

I think you need to provide the read capacity and write capacity for the index when it is created - it will not inherit any values from the parent table. Although if the table is using autoscaling, the autoscaling configuration can be automatically applied to the GSI. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.Console.html#AutoScaling.Console.ExistingTable

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'd missed that page in the docs. Now it's more clear.

Comment: Interesting.. So using projection type as ALL in a GSI will implicates in duplicates costs for writing in that table? Using same logic, two GSI with projection ALL will triplicate costs for writing in that table? If so, then projection ALL will be always more expensive than KEYS_ONLY because is always cheaper two reading operations than two writing operations - except cases where document has less than a write unit. What you think?

Comment: @Brian Winant : Just to add to your answer, the RCU costs don't depend on whether GSI is ALL or KEYS_ONLY or INCLUDE. Rather, the cost depends on amount of data you are reading. 
https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/
So, depending on eventual/strongly consistent read, you can fetch 8KB/4KB per RCU irrespective of the projection type. So, if your record is small enough to fit within 4KB for a strongly consistent read, you can set GSI to ALL projection and fetch the entire data in 1 RCU itself.

Comment: @guijob "projection ALL will be always more expensive than KEYS_ONLY" is usually not right. You cannot avoid WCU to write GSI, and ALL and KEYS_ONLY will be the same 1WCU cost if item is < 1KB. And with ALL projection, you save one RCU when you want to read all attributes.

Comment: @GuangtongShen . Interesting comment. I've been pondering about this for many many months. When you said that it "is usually not right", this is based on the assumption that the item is <1KB right? If the item is >1KB, `ALL` projection **will** always be more expensive than `KEYS_ONLY`?

Comment: @SimonSays:  Assume an item with 3 fields [PK, V, GSI_K] is 2KB and the size of [PK, GSI_K] is <1KB. 

KEYS_ONLY GSI: a write costs 3 WCU, reading [PK, GSI_K] costs 1RCU, reading [GSI_K, V] costs 2RCU (because of "Back to main table")

Project ALL GSI: a write costs 4 WCU, reading [PK, GSI_K] costs 1RCU, reading [GSI_K, V] costs 1RCU.        So it depends on whether it's read-heavy and what needs to be read.